# Safari 5 has an issue with HTMLInsertElement?

Tags: javascript, safari

I have the following snippet that seems to work fine in browsers other than Safari 5:

```
jQuery(function($){

    var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload");
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-image");

    fileInput.addEventListener("change",function(e){
        var files = this.files;
    },false);

    fileDiv.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        $(fileInput).show().focus().click().hide();
        e.preventDefault();
    },false);
});
```

When the user clicks, it opens the upload-image window, but when a file is selected it doesn't trigger the "change" portion.  From what I can tell, Safari 5 doesn't seem to recognize the HTMLInputElement.  In more recent version of Safari, the HTMLInputElement has a list of variables (if I print it in the console), but in Safari 5 it is empty.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Why use `.click()` instead of `.change()` to invoke the `change` event?

Comment: `fileDiv.addEventListener("click"`... opens the window for the user to select a file.  I believe it then amends `fileInput` which is supposed to be picked up by the `change` event

Comment: Have you tried binding your event handlers with jQuery? They may have a built-in fix for this.

Comment: Pretty sure that is already happening.  I have a jquery.php file that includes the following snippet `function _change($element = 'this', $js = ''){return $this->_add_event($element, $js, 'change');}`

Comment: The only thing I can figure out is that the file isn't being uploaded, even though the window opens.  It only seems to happen in Safari 5, so it's difficult to troubleshoot (since the code seems to work fine).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Safari 5 doesn't like it when javascript hides the file input.  I removed `.hide()`

and in css added:

```
opacity: 0;
height: 0;
width: 0;
```